# How do defining the first and last day of the month

Tags: sql, sas

I have a question for you. Is there a chance to create a macro something similar to this, but in prco sql in quera where it always selects the first day and the last of the month.

```
%let thismonth=%sysfunc(putn(%sysfunc(today()),yymmn6.));

    where t1.DATE = &thismonth
        and _dly.  between t2.data_from and t2.data_to 
        and &gv_date_dly.  between t3.data_from and t3.data_to 
        and t3.obj_code not in ('G07','N06','N07')
```

where we have date from to be recalled from the 1st day of the month and date_to to the last day of the month when the function & thismonth was called

Comment: It is not clear what you want here.  Do you want the current month (the month of the date generated by the TODAY() function)? Or some other month? If some other month what is the source?  The macro variable? Some variable in the data being queried?  Are you trying to find observations where a particular variable is exactly one of those two days (first of month or last of month)? Or values where the date falls in some interval? Or values where some interval indicated by two dates in the data include the date? Or overlap any part of the month?

Comment: Show some input data and the resulting output desired.  Include example of date that is selected and data which isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining the first / last day of current month:

```
%let first = %sysfunc(intnx(month,%sysfunc(today()),0,b));
%let last  = %sysfunc(intnx(month,%sysfunc(today()),0,e));
```

Comment: Thanks ! and i should transform my code for this : `
 where t1.Date between &first_day and &last_day
 and t2.data_from = &first and t2.data_to = &last
 and t3.data_from = &first and t3.data_to = &last`  ?